# UIDocumentInteractionController annotation property usage

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uikit, sharing

I am using `UIDocumentInteractionController` to share an image taken in my app with an other application.
When you use this to share with Instagram, you can set the annotation property with a dictionary containing the key `@"InstagramCaption"`, which will pre-fill the comment.

I would like to know if it is possible to do this with other applications, and if so what are the keys for the dictionary.

I'm mainly interested to do this with the messages app and the mail app (title and body), but if you know the keys for other apps that allow document interaction it would be great too (Facebook, Twitter, WhatsApp, Path, Tumblr, ...).

Here is what I do :

```
- (void)openImageInOtherApp:(UIImage *)image
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *tempDirectoryURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory()];
    NSURL *imageURL = [tempDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.jpeg" isDirectory:NO];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8);
    BOOL saveSucceeded = [imageData writeToURL:imageURL options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];

    if (!saveSucceeded || error) {
        NSLog(@"Error : Saving image %@ at URL %@ failed with error : %@", image, imageURL, error);
        return;
    }

    UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController = [[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc] init];
    interactionController.delegate = self;
    interactionController.URL = imageURL;
    NSString *comment = @"A test comment"; // A comment that will be sent along with the image
    if (comment != nil && comment.length > 0) {
        interactionController.annotation = @{@"someKey": comment};
    }
    self.interactionController = interactionController;

    BOOL canOpenDocument = [interactionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:self.view.bounds inView:self.view animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"canOpenDocument : %@", canOpenDocument ? @"YES" : @"NO");
}
```

Then the system view appears where I can choose an app that can open the file.

Comment: it is just wasting of Time

Comment: Could you please make sample of you current code?

Comment: I just edited my answer with the code that I use. The code is not the issue though, I just don't know how to setup the annotation dictionary to send along a comment with the image.

Comment: did you read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share/ this

Answer (score 1):

Read **API developer documents(Facebook, Twitter, WhatsApp, Path, Tumblr, ...)**.

Example

1. [API developer facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share/)

   `// Put together the dialog parameters`

   ```
   NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  @"Sharing Tutorial", @"name",
                                  @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
                                  @"Allow your users to share stories on Facebook from your app using the iOS SDK.", @"description",
                                  @"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share/", @"link",
                                  @"http://i.imgur.com/g3Qc1HN.png", @"picture",
                                  nil];
   ```
2. [API developer twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets)
3. [API developer tumblr](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2)

This might helps you :)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer my question. I am not trying to share on Facebook or Twitter using the API but using the UIDocumentInteractionController. Also, as I mentioned, I would like to know how to do this for the Messages app and the Mail app, the rest is just a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

The `UIDocumentInteractionController` is not going to magically support all of those platforms. Some of those use an API which will provide you with more options.

Take a look at [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/index.html) for creating a MMS for the Messages app.

Use [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/index.html) for sending an email with an image attachment.